# Currency Symbol and Code dynamic

Tags: android, currency, symbols, currency-formatting

I am implementing amount of different countries where I need to show Currency symbols. 
I will get dynamic **Currency Code** like *"USD, "EURO","INR"* which are returned by Google API, according to these code I have to display their respective **Currency Symbol** like $, etc., 
I have done following :

```
MyCurrency[] MyCurrencyAll ={   new MyCurrency("$", "dollar sign"),   new MyCurrency("¢", "cent sign"),   new MyCurrency("£", "pound sign"),   new MyCurrency("¤", "currency sign")};
```

But these dollar sign , pound sign will not be taken by Localisation.

So what can be done to do this as I have tried localisation also but there also I am getting error.

PLease help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code to get currency symbol

```
  public static String getCurrencySymbol(String countryCode) {
        // Locale locale = new Locale("", countryCode);
        Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(countryCode);
        String symbol = currency.getSymbol();
        return symbol;
    }
```

for more reference see this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getSymbol()